# Unexpected token i in JSON at position 6 - react redux app

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I am creating a simple react redux app
and I have the data in json format i.e. characters.json

the problem is that when I start the app I get a 
Unexpected token i in JSON at position 6

could you tell what's wrong here?

```
[
{
id: 0,
name: "Superman",
strength: 10,
intelligence: 7,
speed: 9
},
{
id: 1,
name: "Batman",
strength: 7,
intelligence: 10,
speed: 6
},
{
id: 2,
name: "Wonderwoman",
strength: 5,
intelligence: 9,
speed: 7
},
{
id: 3,
name: "Flash",
strength: 5,
intelligence: 6,
speed: 10
},
{
id: 4,
name: "Green Lantern",
strength: 7,
intelligence: 8,
speed: 7
},
{
id: 5,
name: "Aquaman",
strength: 8,
intelligence: 7,
speed: 8
},
{
id: 6,
name: "Cyborg",
strength: 9,
intelligence: 8,
speed: 6
},
{
id: 7,
name: "Green Arrow",
strength: 5,
intelligence: 9,
speed: 7
},
{
id: 8,
name: "Hawkman",
strength: 5,
intelligence: 8,
speed: 8
},
{
id: 9,
name: "Supergirl",
strength: 10,
intelligence: 9,
speed: 7
}
]
```

and this is the code for the main index.js file

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import App from './components/App';
import {createStore} from 'redux';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import rootReducer from './reducers';

const store = createStore(rootReducer);
console.log('store.getState()',store.getState());

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
    <App/>
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('root')
    );
```

Comment: so, why am I getting the error i mentioned above

Comment: That’s not JSON. JSON has quoted keys.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would guess that it is because the keys are unquoted, because the first key starts with an `i`.

Some (most?) JSON parsers do not support unquoted keys as the specifications (RFC, ECMA) require keys to be quoted strings.

The parsers that do support unquoted keys do it mostly for convenience, although it is less desirable in terms of interoperability. It is strongly advised to not rely on this and to always produce JSON documents that have quoted keys.

```
[
  {
    "id": 0,
    "name": "Superman",
    "strength": 10,
    "intelligence": 7,
    "speed": 9
  },
  ...
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON object's keys must be quoted. Try to validate it [here](https://jsonlint.com/)